# Deep level JSON Object referencing

Tags: arrays, json, react-native

I have searched and reviewed similar posts on this subject but no luck. I have valid JSON data returned to my app from my firebase Database but unable to reference the elements beyond first level.  I need to pull the elements (url link) of the photos array object that is also an object of gallery array object. When i use the code snippet below I get the red screen listing all of the JSON object in the gallery object.

```
 <TouchableOpacity  >
                    <Image  
                        source={{ uri: gallery }} 
                        style={styles.roundedNavImageStyle}
                    />
              </TouchableOpacity>
```

[image: red screen showing returned data]

When I change the source to reference what I need given the screenshot, I get errors "Cannot read property of [0] of undefined or Cannot read property photos of undefined.

```
 <TouchableOpacity  >
                    <Image  
                        source={{ uri: gallery[0].photos }} 
                        style={styles.roundedNavImageStyle}
                    />
              </TouchableOpacity>
```

Please help me. The photo links are the only elements of my JSON data I am unable to access which I need badly.  I am able to access the image elements and other textual elements. I have also tried to simplify my JSON by removing the gallery node and starting with a photos node but getting the same issues. Thanks for your anticipated help.  Please use my case rather than a generic json object to help me quicker.

Here's a snipet of my JSON object as stored in Firebase backend.

```
"places": [{

        "id": "a",
        "image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/obisi7/image/upload/v1537575323/tourNaija/slave/slavePic.jpg",
        "title": "Slave Trade Museum",
        "description": "Excerpts from Freeman Institute",
        "subTitle": "One of many rare gems of history and education",
        "phone": "",
        "credit": "The Freeman Institute",
"gallery": [{
            "id": "v1",

    "photos": [{
            "id": "p1",
            "pic1": "https://res.cloudinary.com/obisi7/image/upload/v1537575322/tourNaija/slave/abolitionCannon.jpg",
            "pic2": "https://res.cloudinary.com/obisi7/image/upload/v1537575322/tourNaija/slave/holdingCell.jpg",
            "pic3": "https://res.cloudinary.com/obisi7/image/upload/v1537575322/tourNaija/slave/slaveMarket.jpg",
            "pic4": "https://res.cloudinary.com/obisi7/image/upload/v1537575323/tourNaija/slave/slaveNoReturn.jpg",
            "pic5": "https://res.cloudinary.com/obisi7/image/upload/v1537575323/tourNaija/slave/bibleAtBadagry.jpg",
            "pic6": "https://res.cloudinary.com/obisi7/image/upload/v1537575322/tourNaija/slave/bridge.jpg"

        }]
}]

    },
```

Comment: You can access the image reference  in this way  source={{ uri: gallery[0].photos[0].pic1 }}

Comment: getting '0' of undefined gallery still.  Also, the idea is to render  all of the photos (pic1, pic2, etc in one read). I tried using the map function to get to each link but still same issue.

Comment: Can you check and show the the output of console.log(gallery[0].photos)

Comment: As I indicated, I can't even get that console.log because I get the error "cannot read '0' of undefined gallery upon app start. But when I console.log gallery, it shows the json data so I am confused.